# Converting Swift 3 code without use of dispatch_once_t

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, watchkit, swift3

Prior to migrating to Swift 3, I had the following code:

```
//Set up singleton object for the tracker
class func setup(tid: String) -> WatchGATracker {
    struct Static {
        static var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0
    }
    dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
        _analyticsTracker = WatchGATracker(tid: tid)
    }
    return _analyticsTracker
}
```

I get the following error:

```
'dispatch_once_t' is unavailable in Swift: Use lazily initialized globals instead
```

Apparently, the conversion tool converted the code to this:

```
 class func setup(_ tid: String) -> WatchGATracker {
    struct Static {
        static var onceToken: Int = 0
    }
    _ = WatchGATracker.__once
    return _analyticsTracker
}
```

And at the top of my class, it added this:

```
private static var __once: () = {
        _analyticsTracker = WatchGATracker(tid: tid)
}()
```

But I still get an error:

```
Instance member 'tid' cannot be used on type 'WatchGATracker'
```

tid is declared as:

```
fileprivate var tid: String
```

It used to be declared as:

```
private var tid: String
```

I cannot seem to figure out how to fix my code, does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You shouldn't be using this outdated method of creating singletons anyways, check out a tutorial like [this one](http://krakendev.io/blog/the-right-way-to-write-a-singleton) for a way to do this in Swift.

Comment: why don't you use `lazy` then?

Comment: @holex - Annoyingly, unlike `static` and globals, `lazy` doesn't ensure thread-safety, so you have to implement your own synchronization mechanism.

Comment: @Rob, that is true, however that must be a very special circumstance when an app would try to instatiante a singleton from two different threads approximetly the same time – 99.99% of the cases the `lazy` is a perfect solution.

Comment: Agreed, in practice. But it just gives me the heebie-jeebies to unnecessarily replace a thread-safe pattern with one that isn't, esp since he's trying to do a singleton and there are such simple Swift patterns that preserve thread-safety.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you expect this code to do. What should happen if someone calls `WatchGATracker.setup(tid: "abc")` and then later calls `WatchGATracker.setup(tid: "123")`? It seems the latter tid is quietly ignored. I don't believe this is a correct singleton.

You need to be more explicit about what correct behavior is. For example, if it is a programming error not to call `setup` before using the tracker, you want something like this:

```
class WatchGATracker {
    static private(set) var instance: WatchGATracker!

    class func setup(tid: String) {
        precondition(instance == nil)
        instance = WatchGATracker(tid: tid)
    }

    init(tid: String) { . . . }
}
```

If different parts of the program may call with different tids, then you should do something more like:

```
static private var instances: [String: WatchGATracker] = [:]

class func setup(tid: String) -> WatchGATracker {
    if let instance = instances[tid] {
        return instance
    }

    let instance = WatchGATracker(tid: tid)
    instances[tid] = instance
    return instance
}
```

(As noted in the comments, if you want thread-safety for this fetch, then you'll need to add a class-level dispatch queue to manage it in the same way that you would add an instance-level dispatch queue to handle thread-safety at that level. You don't get automatic thread safety once initialization requires a parameter.)

Comment: Noted. Solving that is identical to solving it in the instance case. `dispatch_once` is not applicable for things that take parameters to construct, and neither are lazy globals.

Answer (score 0):

When the error says "Use lazily initialized globals instead", it's suggesting something like:

```
class WatchGATracker {
    private var tid: String
    static let shared = WatchGATracker(tid: "foo")
    private init(tid: String) { ... }
    ...
}
```

Or, if you really want to give the caller a chance to set the `tid` (which is curious pattern for a singleton), change `init` to not take a parameter, make `tid` implicitly unwrapped but not `private` at all, and declare `shared` like:

```
class WatchGATracker {
    var tid: String!
    static let shared = WatchGATracker()
    private init() { ... }
    ...
}
```

and then you can do

```
WatchGATracker.shared.tid = "foo"
```

---

By the way, regarding `fileprivate`, it's suggesting that merely because that's what the old `private` now translates to. But unless you've got some reason it needs to be `fileprivate`, I'd probably switch it back to `private` (which now makes it private to the lexical scope).

Comment: Thank you, pretty straight forward fix, I will be trying it out. If the app runs like it has done in the past, i'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

We've all gotten used to over-complicated singleton patterns... It's actually very simple now:

```
class WatchGATracker {
    static let sharedInstance = WatchGATracker()
    private override init() {}
}
```

Source: http://krakendev.io/blog/the-right-way-to-write-a-singleton

As for the `setup()` function, I agree with @Rob Napier above in his answer but I'll go a step further. If you're trying to reconfigure a singleton you're doing it wrong.  If you have some required setup parameter that varies from one usage to another you should create separate instances.

Maybe there's some kind of connectivity or other function you're trying to reuse that's leading you down the singleton path but if that's the case you should extract just that function to it's own class and let these configurable instances share *that* singleton.

```
/// Watch Connection singleton
class WatchConnection: NSObject  {
    static let sharedInstance = WatchConnection()
    private override init() {}

    func doSomething() {}
}

//Watch tracker class for each instance of a watch
class WatchGATracker {
    init(tid: String) {
        //do something useful
    }

    let connection = { WatchConnection.sharedInstance }()
}

let one = WatchGATracker(tid: "one")
one.connection.doSomething()
```